# Import .ui during definition of QMainWindow

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

i'm trying to load a "mw.ui" file (made with Qt creator) as the design to be used on my Main Window.

I successfully load a class with:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore, uic
mw = uic.loadUi("mw.ui")
```

but i can't define my class since I already have my object built. I tried to compile the mw.py during execution with

```
uic.compileUi("mw.ui", "mw.py")
```

but i have the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "myFile.py", line 26, in 
>       uic.compileUi("mw.ui", "mw.py")
>
> File "C:\Users\giovanni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic__init__.py", line 162, in compileUi
>
> pyfile.write(_header % (uifname, PYQT_VERSION_STR))
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

I read that i can use pyuic4 to convert the ui to a py file but doing so every small change need a long work (compiling, etc)

I tried to "save as" with qtCreator but i can't find the PY in the infinite list of available formats

Is there a way to load the UI file in "class definition phase" without converting with pyuic4 every single changes? For me it will be ok to implement a script that compile at the begin with uic.compileUi or something similar

Thanks

Comment: What is this object that you already have built? How are you intending to use this object with the ui (which I assume is a `QMainWindow`)? I don't see how pre-compiling the ui is going to help you, since the end result will be exactly the same.

Comment: I want to add methods, events, etc... If i build the class i can extend the qmainwindow but i must define the layout coding, that's confusing. If i call UIC.loadui i get a standard qmainwindow without the event-methods i need. I want to extend the class but keeping the layout into the ui file

Answer (score 0):

I get it with

```
class MainW(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
         super(MainW, self).__init__(*args)
         uic.loadUi("mw.ui", self)
```

from: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html

> PyQt4.uic.loadUi(uifile[, baseinstance=None[, package=”[, resource_suffix=’_rc’]]])
>
> baseinstance – the optional instance of the Qt base class. If
>   specified then the user interface is created in it. Otherwise a new
>   instance of the base class is automatically created.